# How to specify file type in ffmpeg (-f) for both the input and output?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to convert the stdin (pipe:0) to stdout (pipe:1).
My input format is "s16le" and my output format is "wav".
How do I specify the two different formats in an ffmpeg command?

I'm also using two different frequencies (-ar), input 44100Hz and output 22050Hz, how do I specify the two different frequencies in an ffmpeg command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In FFmpeg, the parameters come before the input/output, for that specific input/output.

In your case, your command would look something like:

```
ffmpeg -sample_rate 44100 -f s16le -i - -ar 22050 -codec copy -f wav -
```

In this case, `-ar 44100` and `-f s16le` apply to the input, since they came before the input.

`-ar 22050`, `-codec copy`, and `-f wav` apply to the output, since they were after the input but before the output.

Comment: Don't forget `-channels` input option: for s16le the default value `1`. Also, the sample rate input option for this demuxer is nominally `-sample_rate`, not `-ar`. See `ffmpeg -h demuxer=s16le`.

Comment: Also, I believe stdin is pipe:0 and stdout is pipe:1 in ffmpeg instead of the "-" like most other programs.

Comment: @CMalasadas `-codec copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode which will avoid re-encoding.

Comment: Yeah, out of habit I always explicitly list `-codec copy` if that's what I want.  My configs tend to get updated over time, and if I change my container that might have a different default codec for its usage, I'd hate to accidentally start transcoding things by neglecting the `-codec copy`.  So, I always specify codec, even if it's not necessary in this case.